# NSDictionary mutableCopy raises exc_bad_access

Tags: objective-c, copy, nsarray, automatic-ref-counting, resource-leak

After copying the keys in NSDictionary, I get a crash. I am using ARC. What is the reason?

```
-(NSArray*) findClosestPointsAroundPoint: (NSDictionary*) p inTable: (NSString*) table {

NSMutableArray* fields = [[p allKeys] mutableCopy];}

(gdb) po table
0xef7b880 does not appear to point to a valid object.
```

Answer (score 0):

Presumably the `table` hasn't been set, or has been set to a nil value. Try `NSLog(@"TABLE ->%@"<- TABLE, table);` to see what the value of `table` is.